# Не обрабатывается запрос после нажатия на кнопку Reactjs

Tags: ajax, spring, reactjs, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Пишу фронтенд на React JS. возникла проблема, связанная с формой. Нажимаю на кнопку(первый раз запрос не выполняется), нажимаю ее еще раз ответ приходит, но браузер пишет еще и ошибку. В чем проблема?

**Ниже приведен cityForm.js файл, в котором отправляется ajax запрос:**

```
    class CityForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        var city = props.city;
        var cityIsValid = this.validateCity(city);


        this.state = {city: city, cityValid: cityIsValid, urlCity: ""};

        this.onCityChange = this.onCityChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    validateCity(city) {
        if (city.length > 2) return true;
        return false;
    }

    onCityChange(e) {
        var val = e.target.value;
        console.log(val);
        var valid = this.validateCity(val);
        this.setState({city: val, cityValid: valid});
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (this.state.cityValid === true) {

            var urlCity = "http://localhost:8182/city/" + this.state.city;

            this.setState({urlCity: urlCity});

        }

    }

    render() {
        // цвет границы для поля для ввода имени
        // цвет границы для поля для ввода возраста
        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <p>
                        <label>Страна:</label><br />
                        <input type="text" value={this.state.city}
                               onChange={this.onCityChange}/>
                    </p>

                    <input type="submit" value="Отправить"/>
                </form>
                <CommentBox url={this.state.urlCity}/>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
    loadCommentsFromServer: function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: this.props.url,
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            success: function (data) {
                this.setState({data: data});
            }.bind(this),
            error: function (xhr, status, err) {
                console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
            }.bind(this)
        });
    },
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {data: []};
    },
    componentDidMount: function () {


    },
    render: function () {
        if (this.props.url != "") {
            this.loadCommentsFromServer();
        }

        return (

            <div className="commentBox">

                <h1>Название страны</h1>

                <CommentList data={this.state.data}/>

            </div>
        );
    }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
    render: function () {


        console.log("commentlist1");
        console.log(this.props.data);

        if (this.props.data != "") {
            console.log("commentlist2");
            var city = weathers.city;
            var cityName = "";
            console.log(weathers);
            var commentNodes = weathers.list;
            if (commentNodes != null) {
                cityName = city.name;
                console.log(commentNodes);
                console.log(cityName);
                <div>{cityName}</div>
            }
        }
        console.log("commentlist3");
        return (

            <div></div>

        );
    }
});


ReactDOM.render(
    <CityForm city=""/>,
    document.getElementById("container")
)
```

**А вот index.html файл:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>React Tutorial</title>
    <!-- Not present in the tutorial. Just for basic styling. -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@15.3.0/dist/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@15.3.0/dist/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6.15.0/babel.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.2/marked.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/remarkable@1.7.1/dist/remarkable.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/babel" src="cityForm.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```